# "xargs -a file" to copy files to a folder

Tags: linux, xargs, cp

I am tring to use `xargs -a` to read the contents of a file that has a list of filenames in it.

My directory working in looks like:

```
backups
file1.bak
file2.bak
file3.bak
bakfiles.txt
```

File name with filenames in it: `bakfiles.txt`

bakfiles.txt contents:

```
file1.bak
file2.bak
file3.bak
```

So essentially I'm trying to copy `file1.bak,file2.bak,file3.bak` into the folder `backups`. But using the contents of `bakfiles.txt` to do so.

I tried:

```
xargs -a bakfiles.txt | cp {} backups
```

But I get the error:

```
cp: cannot stat `{}': No such file or directory
```

I should mention i also tried:

```
xargs -a bakfiles.txt cp {} backups
```

And get the error:

```
cp: target `file3.bak' is not a directory
```

Comment: The first attempt is definitely wrong. From looking at the xargs manpage, with your second attempt, try putting single ticks around the braces. Like: xargs -a bakfiles.txt -I'{}' cp '{}' backups

Comment: That did not work. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I just tried it in tsch and bash and it worked fine for me. Did you use the latest version of my comment? I had to update it several times as I kept screwing it up.

Comment: i found a way using cp -t folder, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the following link i figured it out:

https://superuser.com/questions/180251/copy-list-of-files

Heres the command:

xargs -a bakfiles.txt cp -t backups

Answer (score 11):

This works for me on Windows 7 using mks toolkit version of 'xargs'

`cat bakfiles.txt | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' backups/'{}'`

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS release 6.8 (Final) with tcsh shell.

Comment: This works fine when the bakfiles.txt contains only the filenames. If the files to be backed up are in some folder stucture it won't work.                                                              Better Solution: cp <($bakfiles) backups/.